# Joining attribute by location in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, spatial-join

I have two equal point layers (76300 features) with different attributes as a result of queries with the "point sampling tool". Now I want to merge the attribute tables using the "join attribute by location" tool. Whatever "geometric predicate" i use (although i think it should be "equals") the result is just one point.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you mean the output only contains one point (i.e. one feature)?

Comment: It could be that the points don't quick have the same geometry. Try using the NNJoin plugin and joining to the nearest point

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Yes i tried it several time and the result was just one feature (point). However,  I figured out that with less points and a "precision" value it works.